# Sum a Column if it matches a Criteria in one formula - is it possible?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I have two columns of revenue figures of different brands: Example

```
               US     UK
Brand 1       100     0
Brand 2       200     50
Brand 3       100     40
Brand 4        0      20
```

What I am trying to do is SUM the UK column IF and only if US AND UK are bigger than 0 (Revenue>0), Therefore my output would be 90.

How do I do this in one formula - is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Use SUMIFS formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `SUMIFS()` like.

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C5,B2:B5,">0",C2:C5,">0")
```

[image]